# Press a specific key every sec in a game

Tags: c#

I would like to write a program in visual studio c#, that press a specific key on the keyboard every sec.
I tried it with InputSimulator, but it didn't work. Works only on the notepad, but not in the games.
I need some solution for the game part.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I didn't downvote your question (only close-voted as duplicate), but as a general recommendation for future questions, it's helpful if you provide some [mcve] of your code inside the question itself, it helps have your question better received by the community. Also, take some time to read the [tour] and [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Normal input handling uses the [Windows Message Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows). .Net and C# are no exception. This is hidden from you in most platforms, but it's there, and it can introduce latency into your input.

Games don't like latency. To get around this, they use special input handling. What that looks like will vary from game to game, meaning *there's no one way to do what you want.* But you could start by looking at `XInput`, which is replacing the old DirectInput API.